# C# Filter ListView without setting the ItemSource new

Tags: c#, listview, filter

I wonder if it is possible to filter a `ListView` in C# without setting a different `ItemSource`.

Now I'm setting a new `ItemsSource` every time the condition changes:

```
ListView.ItemsSource = list.Where(item => {<<condition>>});
```

My problem: In this list I have user profiles containing a picture. Everytime I set a new ItemSource the pictures are reloaded. Is it possible to use something like the filter in android to just "hide" the rows that don't meet the above condition?

Comment: this is what a collectionviewsource is for. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks good, i'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid actually changing the ItemsSource by instead adding or removing items from an ObservableCollection that is set as the ItemsSource.  The list control will pick up the ObservableCollection events relating to these inserts and deletes and update as appropriate.

e.g. the following function should populate a filtered list from a full list according to a filter expression.  If the filtered list is bound to a list control then just calling this function should have the desired effect.

```
static void FilterList<T>(List<T> masterList, ObservableCollection<T> filteredList, Func<T, bool> filterExpression)
{
    foreach (var item in masterList)
    {
        if (filterExpression(item))
        {
            if (!filteredList.Contains(item))
            {
                filteredList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (filteredList.Contains(item))
            {
                filteredList.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e.g.

> FilterList(allCars, filteredCars, (user) => user.Age >= 50);

Note though that this function will probably need additional logic to retain the ordering rather than always adding new filtered items to the end.